# How to create a user in Azure API Management REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I followed the example which was provided by Azure documentation. [Azure documentation section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/users). However i got 404 resource not found error all the time.

This is the URL i used - https://xxxx.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxxx/users/xxxxxx?api-version=2016-07-07

Header as - Authorization: SharedAccessSignature ###########

Further subscription id, resource group and service name was taken from properties. Which was shown in below image.

[image]

I couldn't find an error in my code and please help me to solve this issue.

Updated response image

[image]

Comment: so what request are you sending exactly?

Comment: I tried Create Or Update request (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/users). Did you try to create users in Azure Rest API management?

Comment: can you update your question with the request you are sending? obviously, remove all the sensitive information

Comment: Ok sure ill do that now

Comment: Have you tried this from Fiddler or Postman? Also, be sure to use the PUT (not POST) http operation

Comment: I updated the request image please check that. For @Erik Oppedijk, yes I used PUT request

Comment: url is wrong? you forgot the `/providers/.../`? does sharedaccesssignrature have `uid=keygoeshere?`

Comment: This is the URL, I used - "xxxx.management.azure-api.net/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxxxx/users/xxxxxx?api-version=2016-07-07"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what worked for me:

PUT https://{apim-name}.management.azure-api.net/users/{username}?api-version=2016-07-07

```
headers:  
Authorization = SharedAccessSignature KEY  
Content-Type = application/json

body:  
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "Qwerty123$",
    "firstname": "name",
    "lastname": "notname"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mixed up the old REST url with the new one:

Try https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/yyyy

You used the old REST URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/api-management-rest
which expects /users

The documentation on this doesn't mention this very clearly!
With the new URL you will receive 401 messages (unauthorized)

You will also need to authenticate on a different way, take a look at this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore

EXAMPLE:

> GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/{MY_RG_APIMANAGEMENT}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{MY_APIM_NAME}/users?api-version=2014-02-14
>
> headers:
>    Authorization = Bearer {KEY}
>    Content-Type = application/json

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to talk to `https://{APIMname}.management.azure-api.net`

Comment: I use this URL for starting the backup of APIM. Your URL works, but then you need to call: https://{APIMname}.management.azure-api.net/users

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: doesn't work with `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{apim-name}/users/test?api-version=2016-07-07`

Comment: @ErikOppedijk Thanks for you help too.

Comment: I'm finding this new REST API confusing. Seems like a lot of unrelated steps to go through to get an auth token. The old management API just required a click and a copy-paste from the portal to get the SAS key. Was there any announcement of the new API? I just stumbled on it in the docs this week.